# Construct many nested class members

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to create an base class to handle many SQL statements for different database systems.

My basic idea was this:

```
struct BaseSQLStmts {

    BaseSQLStmts(Database db) : db(db) {};

    // nested operator class Cmd.
    struct Cmd {
        Cmd(Database db, const char *sqlStmt)
        : db(db), sqlStmt(sqlStmt), sqlHandle(Database::noHandle)
        {};


        Database::Handle operator() () {
            if (sqlHandle==Database::noHandle) {
                sqlHandle = db->prepareSQL(sqlStmt);
            }

            return sqlHandle;
        }

        Database db;
        const char *sqlStmt;
        Database::Handle sqlHandle;
    };

    // SQL-Statement to construct with database and SQL.
    Cmd theSqlStmt;

    // And many more (>50) members of type Cmd.

private:
    Database db;
};

// later use:
BaseSQLStmts *dbSql = new SQLStmtsClassForDB(db);
// ...
db->execute(dbSql->theSqlStmt());
```

The problem is, how to construct all the members (over 50) of type `BaseSQLStmts::Cmd` with database and SQL-Statements by creating a derived class. I could define a `const char *` parameter for each SQL at the constructor, but it's an error-prone number of parameters. Virtual member functions to get named SQL statements `virtual const char* theSqlStmtSQL() = 0` didn't work with the constructor (pure virtual member). Constructing within the derived class also did not work.

Any good idea how to handle this by checking completeness of the statements by compile time?

Comment: Basic containers like `vector` and `map` should not be considered "complex data structures". A *database* is a complex data structure, not an array.

Comment: @NicolBolas: My intension is to check completeness (and as far as possible correctness) by compile time. This did not work with containers or arrays.

Answer (score 1):

> Any good idea how to handle this without using a complex data structures

That's self contradictory. If you have *over 50* values of some type, you *really should* consider putting them in some container.

Surely your 50 queries have something to identify them. Even something like

```
enum Queries { CreateFoo, GetBarOfFooByBaz, ..., Queries_Count }

std::vector<Cmd> commands(Queries_Count);
```

would be helpful.

Comment: My intention is to check completeness of SQL statements at compile time.

Comment: @MarcusHampel: How does that in any way affect how you have to store the data?

Answer (score 0):

Having so many data members seems like a code smell to me. Maybe you should work on your design for this. Also, your request for not using "complex data structures" seems a bit weird to me. First, a vector is not that complex and second, you should absolutely always use STL-containers if appropiate. They are fast, tested and reliable.

Alas, for what you asked, I think the best way would be to put all the `Cmd`s in a seperate class, make them use  and store (a pointer to) an object in your `BaseSQLStmts`, i.e.:

```
struct CmdCollection {
   struct Cmd {
        Cmd(CmdCollection &coll, const char *sqlStmt)
        : collec(coll), sqlStmt(sqlStmt), sqlHandle(Database::noHandle)
        {};


        Database::Handle operator() () {
            if (sqlHandle==Database::noHandle) {
                sqlHandle = collec.db->prepareSQL(sqlStmt);
            }

            return sqlHandle;
        }

        CmdCollection &collec;       
        const char *sqlStmt;
        Database::Handle sqlHandle;
    };

    Database db;
    Cmd cmd1 = Cmd(*this, "STMT1");
    Cmd cmd2 = Cmd(*this, "STMT2");

    CmdCollection(Database db) : db(db) {}
};

struct BaseSQLStmts {

    BaseSQLStmts(Database db) : db(db), col(db) {};    

    // SQL-Statement to construct with database and SQL.
    CmdCollection col;

    // And many more (>50) members of type Cmd.

private:
    Database db;
};
```